# VimL: how to execute a function on a visual selection only once

Tags: vim

I need your help. Suppose I have a function:

```
fun! Foo()
    " Do awesome staff
endfunction
```

And the following key binding in my plugin:

```
vnoremap <LocalLeader>cv :call Foo()<RETURN>
```

My problem is that Foo() gets call for each line of my visual selection. Instead, I just want Foo() to be executed one and only once.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See `:help function-range-example`

```
fun! Foo() range
  " Do awesome stuff
endfun
vnoremap <LocalLeader>cv :call Foo()<cr>
```